# Control + key doesn't work on modifier

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

am trying to catch the key down using Behavior

```
public class mONITORKeyDown : Behavior<UserControl>
    {

        public static readonly DependencyProperty _ShortCuts =
                    DependencyProperty.Register(
                        "ShortCuts",
                        typeof(Dictionary<Tuple<ModifierKeys, Key>, ICommand>),
                        typeof(BillingMangerKeyDown),
                        new PropertyMetadata( null));


        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
          // ShortCuts = new Dictionary<Tuple<ModifierKeys, Key>, ICommand>();
            AssociatedObject.KeyDown += _KeyBoardBehaviorKeyDown;
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {

            AssociatedObject.KeyDown -= _KeyBoardBehaviorKeyDown;
        }



        void _KeyBoardBehaviorKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if(Keyboard.Modifiers == KeyModifiers.Control && e.Key==Key.Down)

        }
        }
```

the problem is that Once I click cntrl ,it fire the event ,and after click enter + down arrow nothing work

Answer (score 1):

**I Think It Should Help You !!!**

```
  private void InvoiceGrid_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control)
        {
            ((ResolutionVM)this.DataContext).PrepareListForMassUpdate();
        }
        else
        {
            ((ResolutionVM)this.DataContext).ClearListForMassUpdate();
        }

    }
```